# Can someone declare an item be collateral without me signing anything? And seize it?

Tags: repayment

I bought a business from someone for $20,000. After paying him everything, yesterday he messaged me, saying that my car is under collateral and he will seize the car if I don’t pay him an extra $5,000. The car is in my dads name. Should I report this to the police? Perhaps I should just leave it because he is asking me for money based on nothing. Is the car safe ?

Comment: what country is this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about business law.

Comment: The short answer is: "No", but depending upon your sales agreement this person may be in the right.  Which is why you NEED a  lawyer.

Comment: Can we assume the contract you signed to buy the business didn't mention the car (or other property) being collateral in any shape of form?

Comment: Taking what you have said at face value ... the person sounds crazy. Call the police and tell them you are being threatened.

Comment: What planet are we talking about?

Comment: Sounds like a scam - are you sure you  'bought a business'? Likely outcome is that you bought worthless paper and this scammer is just going in for more. Get a lawyer + go to the police immediately if you want your original 20k back.

Comment: I'm with @Grade'Eh'Bacon. The collateral shenanigan is so ridiculously outrageous that it throws the previous transaction into doubt.

Answer (score 6):

No, not like this. You may be totally liable for any debt of the business, but seizing things is an official act. Also this is in this case seizing THIRD PARTY collateral as you said the car does not even belong to you.

In this particular case, there is a criminal background. It is called extortion. Report to the police.